# Purposely making two flex container overlap at the same exact specific position

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need to make "flex-container > div4" vertically overlap and/or horizontally align with "flex-container > div2".

Need div2 & div4 to be perfectly centered.

I used text-align to center div2 but div4 is an image.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: blue;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: #ffffff;
   margin-top: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 35px;
 min-width: 150px;
 max-width: 150px;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.flex-container > div2 {
background-color: #ffffff;
flex-shrink: 0;
margin-top: auto;
height: 50px;
  width: 250px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 12px;
  }
  .flex-container > div3 {
 margin-top: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
   width: 150px;
    height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
   line-height: 50px;
   font-size: 15px;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  align-self: flex-start;
  background-color: white;
  }
  .flex-container > divspacer {
   background-color: #ffffff;
   width: 33%;
    height: 35px;
  margin: 1px;
  text-align: center;
   line-height: 50px;
   font-size: 12px;
    }
    .flex-container > div4 {
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">

   <div><img src="https://oakandrocks.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/perfootersmol.png"></div>  
    <div2>
    <a class="inline" style="text-decoration: none" href="https://oakandrocks.com/onr"> Webmasters |</a>
 <a class="inline" style="text-decoration: none" href="https://oakandrocks.com/terms"> Terms & Conditions |   </a>
 <a class="inline" style="text-decoration: none" href="https://oakandrocks.com/privacy"> Privacy Policy   </a>
    </div2>
 <div3><a style="text-decoration: none" href="https://oakandrocks.com/">© 2019 Oak & Rocks</a></div3>
</div>
<div class="flex-container"><div4><img src="https://oakandrocks.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/footertxt.png"></div4></div>
```

So, to conclude, maybe not an overlap, but I need div4 (website solutions png) to be perfectly centered and bottom of the page (maybe ~1px vertical margin)

FIXED:

```
.flexcontainer > div4 {
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: don't add the fix/answer to the question. Either write an answer or delete the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right after posting the question, as usual, I figured a fix.

adding:

```
.flexcontainer > div4 {
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```